# Eclipse doesn't recognize projects

Tags: java, eclipse

I had to reinstall Windows, so I downloaded eclipse again. I saved the workspace folder in MEGA and now Eclipse can't recognize any projects.

I tried to use import and import from workspace or importing from file system, but that didn't work.

Any ideas? I did this many times in the past and is the first time that something like this happens.

Comment: what is the problem exactly what happens when u import?
did you try to import one project at a time?

Comment: I don't know the problem, import from workspace don't show me the list with the projects that are in workspace. One by one, I select the folder or the zip (tried two ways) and can't advance, the finish button is always disabled.

Comment: Your .metadata folder in your workspace directory containing eclipse data may be corrupted.  First try -clean argument on eclipse  start and then if issue remains,  Try backing it up and then deleting it and start with fresh worskpace.

Comment: No results with -clean. I tried to start a new workspace and I created a new project. I saved the project, then I put in the folder other old project. Eclipse only recognize the new project. Any ideas?

Comment: Did the '.project' files get saved? Without those the projects will not be recognized.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar issue using a workspace saved on MEGA on two different computers. I could solve it creating new projects with the same name.

Example:
If you have a folder named `MyProject` in your workspace (assuming it's a java project)

1. Go to `File->New->Java Project`
2. Insert `MyProject` as project name
3. Project is visible in eclipse now

Maybe some further configuration is needed, according to your specific projects.

Hope that helps...

**UPDATE:**
There is an option in MEGA settings, excluding files starting with a dot, what could be the cause for the missing `.project` file.

Answer (score 0):

You must use 
File - Import - General - Import existing project into workspace,  then point to  your project folder and you should be able to see your projects listed in the "projects" area